# Where are the versions of the other spring modules specified in the pom file of spring-data-redis 2.6.1

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, pom.xml

Maven novice here. The pom file of the Spring Data Redis module version 2.6.1 can be found at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/2.6.1/spring-data-redis-2.6.1.pom. The `spring-aop`, and a bunch of other Spring modules don't have a version specified in the file, but when I look at the dependence tree, the version is `5.3.15`.

So where is the version specified?

Answer (score 1):

They come from the parent, which is [`org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:2.6.1`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/build/spring-data-parent/2.6.1/spring-data-parent-2.6.1.pom). That POM contains a [`dependencyManagement` section](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management):

```xml
<properties>
    …
    <spring>5.3.15</spring>
    …
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        …
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And that `spring-framework-bom`, called a [Bill of Materials](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms) (AKA BOM), has all the version of various Spring libraries.

When you import [that BOM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.3.15/spring-framework-bom-5.3.15.pom) in your project, the versions listed in its `dependencyManagement` section become kind of recommendations: they will be used if no other version is specified:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    …
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: It seems they will also be used even if a version is explicitly specified. For example, with only the following 2 dependencies, the final version of spring aop is 5.3.15.
`org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.6.RELEASE`
`org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.6.1`

Comment: It's hard to guess because you didn't share any code, but that may be, indeed. It really depends on what you specify and where.

Comment: `plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.6.RELEASE')
    implementation('org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.6.1')
}`
For example, the above is my build.gradle file. When I run `gradle dependencies` , I get `+--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.6.RELEASE -> 5.3.15` under the `runtimeClasspath`.